# Pydantic behaves abnormally

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to build a Pydantic model in Pydantic version 1.10.2 and python 3.7 with the following fields:

- `overWrite`
- `nas_path`
- `hdfs_dir`
- `convert`
- `file_size_limit`

with these conditions:

1. `file_size_limit` can't be blank or anything other than `int`
2. `convert` can be passed `Y` or `YES` , `N` or `No` it is mandatory and when it is `Yes` or `Y`, `hdfs_dir` field must present, and if it is `N` or `No`, `nas_path` must present.
3. Either `nas_path` or `hdfs_dir` must be there, and it can't be blank.
4. `overWrite` must be `N` or `Y`; if not passed it should be `N`

Based on this I developed the follwong models

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class FileModel(BaseModel):
    overWrite: str = 'N'
    nas_path: str = None
    hdfs_dir: str = None
    convert: str
    file_size_limit: int

    @validator('file_size_limit', pre=True)
    def validate_file_size_limit(cls, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise ValueError('file_size_limit must be an integer')
        return value

    @validator('convert')
    def validate_convert(cls, value, values):
        if value.upper() not in ['Y', 'YES', 'N', 'NO']:
            raise ValueError('convert must be Y, YES, N, or NO')
        if values.get('hdfs_dir') and value.upper() in ['N', 'NO']:
            raise ValueError('convert must be Y or YES when hdfs_dir is present')
        if values.get('nas_path') and value.upper() in ['Y', 'YES']:
            raise ValueError('convert must be N or NO when nas_path is present')
        if value.upper() in ['Y', 'YES'] and not values.get('hdfs_dir'):
            raise ValueError('hdfs_dir is required when convert is Y or YES')
        if value.upper() in ['N', 'NO'] and not values.get('nas_path'):
            raise ValueError('nas_path is required when convert is N or NO')
        return value.upper() in ['Y', 'YES']

    @validator('nas_path', 'hdfs_dir', pre=True, always= True)
    def validate_paths(cls, value, values):
        if not values.get('nas_path') and not values.get('hdfs_dir'):
            raise ValueError('nas_path or hdfs_dir must be provided')
        return value


val = FileModel(**{
    "convert": 'N',
    "overWrite": "Y",
    "nas_path": "sdds",
    "file_size_limit": "2000",
})
print (val, dir(val))
```

But when I call the model with above data it gives me an error:

```
nas_path
  nas_path or hdfs_dir must be provided (type=value_error)
hdfs_dir
  nas_path or hdfs_dir must be provided (type=value_error)
convert
  nas_path is required when convert is N or NO (type=value_error)
```

Ideally it should accept this value as it has `convert` `N` and `nas_path`, both fields are not blank and `file_size_limit`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the fact that you are using regular field validators as [root validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#root-validators). Yes, you *can* access previously validated field values via the optional `values` dictionary argument, but you for example in `validate_paths` you are using that to try and get both the values for `nas_path` **and** for `hdfs_dir`, but there will never be *both* of them in `values` because one of them will always be the first argument passed to the field validator - `value`.

There are more things wrong with your approach, but it is not useful to correct them one by one. (For example, why are you checking if `file_size_limit` is a **string** in your custom validator? It is supposed to be an integer! You don't need a custom validator for that field at all.)

---

Allow me to suggest a totally different approach to accomplish what you are looking for.

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class FileModel(BaseModel):
    file_size_limit: int
    convert: bool
    overWrite: bool = False
    nas_path: Optional[str] = None
    hdfs_dir: Optional[str] = None

    @validator("nas_path", always=True)
    def ensure_present_with_convert_false(
        cls,
        v: Optional[str],
        values: Dict[str, Any],
    ) -> Optional[str]:
        if not values.get("convert") and v is None:
            raise ValueError("`nas_path` is required when `convert` is false")
        return v

    @validator("hdfs_dir", always=True)
    def ensure_present_with_convert_true(
        cls,
        v: Optional[str],
        values: Dict[str, Any],
    ) -> Optional[str]:
        if values.get("convert") and v is None:
            raise ValueError("`hdfs_dir` is required when `convert` is true")
        return v
```

Store boolean fields as actual booleans rather than magic strings. Pydantic is "smart" enough to implicitly coerce strings that can be interpreted as booleans (`"y"` or `"no"` and so on).

Your rule 1) will be ensured by simply annotating `file_size_limit: int`.

The two custom validators together are enough to ensure your rule 2) is honored. Your rule 3) is redundant (included in rule 2). Since `convert` will *always* be either `True` or `False`, our validators already ensure that either `nas_path` or `hdfs_dir` is present.

Rule 4) I would argue the same way that a boolean field makes more sense and you can specify `False` as a default.

The only thing to note is that there is nothing preventing someone from passing *both* `nas_path` and `hdfs_dir`. But you did not specify that this is undesirable. You can just ignore one of them, depending on `convert`. If you absolutely want to forbid it, you could for example add a custom root validator like this:

```py
    @root_validator
    def not_both(cls, values: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        nas_path, hdfs_dir = values.get("nas_path"), values.get("hdfs_dir")
        if nas_path is not None and hdfs_dir is not None:
            raise ValueError("Do not provide both...")
        return values
```

But I doubt this is necessary or useful.

---

Demo: (same data as in your original example)

```py
val = FileModel.parse_obj({
    "convert": "N",
    "overWrite": "Y",
    "nas_path": "sdds",
    "file_size_limit": "2000",
})
print(val.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "file_size_limit": 2000,
    "convert": false,
    "overWrite": true,
    "nas_path": "sdds",
    "hdfs_dir": null
}
```